# Lotus notes read only access

Tags: lotus-notes

Can someone tell me if you have read only access on lotus notes account are you able to forward on emails from the account you have read only access to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lotus notes server](http://serverfault.com/questions/345302/lotus-notes-server)

Comment: Martin - again, if you have reason to suspect illegal activity of your former employer, this is not the place to solicit advice.

Answer (score 1):

When forwarding an email you need to create a new email and enter an email address. If the access in the ACL is "Reader" you will not be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks Jasper! Do you know if there is anyway within the acl of a laptop of proving what access has been provided to another person?

Comment: The access they claim to have was person-reader-write public documents and calendars. Copy and export.